# How to break line in text area using $scope angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use text area for chat input box, because its resizable, in that I want some prefilled texts to be there, like

```
HI Jhon,
Thanks for contacting us....
```

I want to give new line after the text in textarea.
My code-

```
$scope.message = "Hi "+$scope.firstName+ ",Thanks for contacting us....... ";
```

I tried, using break tag but that did'nt worked

```
 <textarea id="typeMessageBox" placeholder="Write here..." type="text submit" ng-model="message"></textarea>
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \n instead of  break tag.

eg: $scope.message = "Hi "+$scope.firstName+ ",\n Thanks for contacting us....... ";